# Required request part

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, jsp

When I add a picture to my table, an error occurs:

> Message Required request part 'picture' is not present
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
>   something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

Nothing is loaded into the database.

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/general")
public class OrderController {
    private OrderService orderService;
    private Dao dao;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setOrderService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    public OrderController() {

    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public String get(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("orders", orderService.getOrders());

        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/showFormForAdd")
    public String add(Model theModel) {
        Orders orders = new Orders();

        theModel.addAttribute("order", orders);

        return "create-orders";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveOrders")
    public String addOrders(@ModelAttribute("order") Orders orders, @RequestParam("picture") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        orders = orderService.uploadOrders(orders, file);
        orderService.add(orders);

        return "redirect:/general/list";
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Repository
public interface Dao {
    List<Orders> getAllOrders();

    void addAll(Orders orders);
}
```

OrderDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class OrderDaoImpl implements Dao {

    private SessionFactory orderDao = OrderDao.getSessionFactory();

    public OrderDaoImpl() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setOrderDao(SessionFactory orderDao) {
        this.orderDao = orderDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Orders> getAllOrders() {
        Session session = orderDao.openSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

            Query<Orders> query = session.createQuery("from Orders", Orders.class);

            return query.getResultList();
        } finally {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addAll(Orders orders) {
        Session session = orderDao.openSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(orders);
        } finally {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

create-orders.jsp:

```
<head>
    <title>Car Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/general/saveOrders" enctype="multipart/form-data"
           modelAttribute="order" method="post">

        <div class="container">
            <div id="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center">Создание объявления</h2>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description" type="table" class="table">Description:</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="description" name="description"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price" type="table" class="table">Price:</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="price" name="price"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="body" type="table" class="table">Body:</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="body" name="body"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="brand" type="table" class="table">Brand:</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="brand" name="brand"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="engine" type="table" class="table">Engine:</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="engine" name="engine"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="model" type="table" class="table">Model:</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="model" name="model"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Sold:</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="sold" type="checkbox" name="sold">
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pic">Image</label>
                        <label>
                            <input id="pic" name="picture" type="file" class="file">
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="saveOrders">Сохранить</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <p>
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/general/list"
                           class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg my-3">Back to Orders list</a>
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form:form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any related classes like Repository ones?

Comment: Yes. It's Dao and OrderDaoImpl. I add it into question.